# Constraint Layout - LayoutAnimation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Is there any way to achieve a layoutAnimation in a group of views in a **constraint layout** without a use of a container layout like `Linear/Relative layout`?

I Have a complex layout with many groups of views like (blocks) and today I have animations using `LayoutAnimationController` to animate all childs of these blocks separately with a delay between them, adding custom interpolators and etc...

I would like to remove these many containers and use only a `ConstraintLayout` but the only thing preventing me to do that is that I'm not sure how to animate all views like in `LayoutAnimationController` (`ConstraintSet` **is not the same** thing at least as far as I tried) and PlaceHolders doesn't seem to have `layoutAnimations` (probably because it's not a ViewGroup).

Comment: this may help you : https://robinhood.engineering/beautiful-animations-using-android-constraintlayout-eee5b72ecae3

Comment: thanks, @Adnanul I already tried things in that article. But as I said, ConstraintSet is for animating changes between constraints which works fine for most cases, but what I have with `LayoutAnimationController` is a custom animation applied to each child view of ViewGroup starting at a different time, ConstraintSet helped me a lot but I still have to figure out how to apply a behaviour like LayoutAnimationController without applying the animation to each view individually at different time

Comment: What is stopping you from using LayoutAnimationController with ConstraintLayout?

Comment: Plus, even if they don‘t work well together, changing to CL and applying the animation logic yourself seem like the right choice IMO.

Comment: @RamiJemli What's is stopping me is if I apply the LayoutAnimationController to the ConstraintLayout all children will be animated and I want specifically groups of views and animate all the logic by myself  for more than 30 views is clearly not an option here as I can do the same with 1 line of code just having nested views . I was just wondering if there is something like `Group` or any `ConstraintHelper` for that in beta. But for now, I will stick with the nested hierarchy as I don't have time to play with ConstraintHelper